# how to get the following link to work in phpmailer

Tags: html

I have the following phpmailer and have displayed the date by using php echo but the problem is that, if the user were to delete the date, then the date won't work. What is the best way to prevent an user from deleting information displayed in the placeholder?

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once __DIR__.'/header2.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php?subscribed=notlogin'>"; 
    exit();
} else {
    if($_SESSION['u_permission'] == 0) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?subscribed=nopermission'>"; 
        exit();
    } else {
        $date = strip_tags(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

                            echo '<form action="subscribed_form.php" method="POST"><table class="subscribed">
                      <tr>
                      <th colspan="3" class="update_title">Welcome to the Administrator\'s Display Subscribed Newsletter Members\s Section</th>
                      </tr>';





                                  echo '
                      <tr>
                      <th>Newsletter\'s name:</th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="Enter Newsletter\'s Name"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Newsletter\'s Description:</th><td><textarea name="description" value="Enter Newsletter\'s Description"></textarea></td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                      <th>Newsletter\'s Date:</th><td><input type="text" name="date" value="'.htmlspecialchars($date).'"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr><th></th><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Newsletters"></td></tr></table></form>';

    }


}
```

Comment: you can make the input `readonly`

Comment: what do you mean by readonly?

Comment: If you make a input `readonly`, which means someone will only be able to read it. So, if you don't want users to modify the date input you can use `<input type="text" name="date" value="'.htmlspecialchars($date).'" readonly="readonly">` (a user can, however, remove the `readonly` attribute and edit the date if they were to use inspect element)

Comment: Is there any way to get around them not using the inspect element?

Comment: not particularly. You'll need to check the date format on the server-side (the backend) once your form has been submitted. As client-side validation can be easily bypassed (eg: using inspect element). So, you'll need to check the date format in the backend, and if it doesn't equal the expect date-format or is the incorrect date then you can give an error, otherwise, you can assume everything is fine